# EF7 UWP SQLite .Include() method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, uwp

Want use Entity Framework 7 (Entity Framework Core) with SQLite in Universal Windows Application.

Can`t find .Include(x => x.SomeNvaigationProperty)

.Include() doesn't appear in intellisense

.Include() in System.Data.Entity

System.Data.Entity not available in UWP

What use in UWP (as .Include())?

```cs
public class Parent
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public List<Child> Childs { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public Guid ParentId { get; set; }
   public Parent Parent { get; set; }
}

dbContext.Parent.Include(x => x.Childs).ToList();
dbContext.Childs.Include(x => x.Parent).ToList();
```

[image]

Comment: Its not clear. What exactly you want? Elaborate little more

Comment: Are you saying that `.Include()` doesn't appear in intellisense? Add `using System.Linq;`

Comment: Yes ".Include() doesn't appear in intellisense"

Answer (score 2):

In Entity Framework 7 *.Include()* placed **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore**

Answer (score 0):

You are adding wrong namespace `using System.Linq` for `.Include()`. 
You need to add `using System.Data.Entity` then you will get `.Include()`